# WebView, HTML, Android and Java. Several problems

Tags: android, html, webview, android-developer-api

There are several problems. It is not necessary to read everything and answer all at once, subtitles problems made that it was immediately clear what we are dealing. In

general, the case. There are two activities. The first - the list ListView, the second

WebView, loaded html files from the raw-resource project. Web element operates under such a simple code:

```
WebView webView;
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "raw", "mypackagename"));

    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", text, "html", "utf-8", null);
```

**Problem 1. Processing pressing Back in webView**

Each html resource under the heading there is a picture-link due to the size, refers to the full size of the pictures. The code in html simple, like a limpet:

```
<a href="file:///android_asset/pic1.jpg"><img src="file:///android_asset/pic1.jpg" height="300dp"></a>
```

When you exit the full-sized pictures, I get on your list and not back into the html file. It was clear that the button "BACK" is perceived by the layout, not webView. After

reading the documentation on Google, I found a way to:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
// Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
    myWebView.goBack();
    return true;
}
// If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
// system behavior (probably exit the activity)
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

It seems to be a simple code should work. But when testing was found that returning from the full image, html file is loaded back and I get a blank white screen, from which I

come back to the list already. May be,

this is due to the fact that I have many html-files, which depending on the desired load. But here I have a guess, and I'm stuck. What do you think on this subject you**?**

Immediately there is a small little whim. What is the unit of measurement (or html tags) can make the image on all screens look the same? On the smartphone - good on the

plate looks too small.

**Problem 2. The old version of android and html background.**
Checking the project on the old phone with a version of **android 2.2**, there was another problem. ListView system color to paint over where was the text, covering my

back background. And he kosyachit (or rather, I kosyachit,sure) in webView. The html file in a way I did the background:

```
<body background="file:///android_res/drawable/background_html.jpg" bgproperties="fixed"></body>
```

Picture background I did (for example) at a rate of 25 * 25, and three times put her picture in 50 * 50, reflecting the ends so that when duplicating images were no

inconsistencies.

On **android 2.2** background image should not be duplicated, and suspended from the tip of the file, and when scrolling the content - the picture of the background goes

with the title, leaving only the backdrop to the white background. Here I do not have

even assumptions. What can you say? It will help install the background to webView through java code?

**Problem 3. WebView and a html link to another file.**
The most frustrating. I also have some html files, links to other files, if there is any mention of (the principle of Wikipedia). Open, for example, **file2.html** Reference is also

framed a simple html tag:

```
<a href="file:///android_res/raw/file4.html">Ссылка на другой html-файл из ресурсов</a>
```

On my phone with version 4.2.2 - everything is loaded as it is necessary, as well as to load would be by going through the list I have.
On the tablet with version 4.4.2 and the other on the phone with a version 5.1 once the link is not loaded html-file in webView, but just shows my content with my code this

same html-file, that is, it opens the way

if I opened a html-file through a notepad. If you switch to this file through the list - all well and good. He should think of it as a html page and build in put right. Somehow,

there is a failure in the script when

there is a re-link. What do you think about this?

**PS:** Thank you in advance everyone who will respond even come across a thought or desired answer at least one question. I wash my inexperience, please. I would be

grateful.

Comment: I'm sorry! I thought, once problems are related to the same topic, then it will be better.

Comment: Yes, off course. Thank you!